# Joint distribution of multivariate normal

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. $N(0, 1)$, and let $S$ be a random sign (1 or -1, with equal probabilities) independent of $(X, Y)$.

\begin{align*}
P((SX,SY)∈B)&=P((X,Y)∈B,S=1)+P((−X,−Y)∈B,S=−1) \\
&= P((X,Y)∈B)P(S=1)+P((−X,−Y)∈B)P(S=−1)\\
&= 0.5*P((X,Y)∈B) + 0.5*P((−X,−Y)∈B)\\
&= P((X,Y)∈B)
\end{align*}

What does this infer about the joint distribution of $(SX, SY)$?. How does it mean that the joint pdf of $(SX, SY)$ and $(X, Y)$ are the same.

Edit: This post is directly linked with the below link. I would like to get a better explanation than the one we have got there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858890/if-joint-probabilities-equal-mean-their-distributions-are-equal

Comment: Looks like you are the same person who posted these questions on Math.SE some time back: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858424/determining-multivariate-normality , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858890/if-joint-probabilities-equal-mean-their-distributions-are-equal. Please note that one should avoid cross-posting if possible.

Comment: It is from a friend of mine. I am trying to help her. But both are lost in the same question. That's why I slightly clarified the question a bit.

Comment: That is fine. But then you could have added the two links in this post saying that you and your friend did not receive much feedback there.